# Angular Routes, Redirects and Guards

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

#### Introduction

In my project I have a setup where I have two routes, route A and route B.

Both of these routes have guards which implement CanActivate interface.

routes code look something like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'a',
  },
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent,
    canActivate: [AGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'unimportant-route',
    component: UnimportantComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'b',
      },
      {
        path: 'b',
        component: BComponent,
        canActivate: [BGuard],
      },
  },
]
```

#### My question

When I go to route 'b' and canActivate redirects me to route 'a' (by returning URLTree) how can i force Angular to run checks on canActivate for `AGuard`?

##### Attention

Crutial part is that the canActivate function returns `URLTree` type value if redirect needs to occur (I dont wanna break this rule in my code)

i tried finding something in documentation, also watched logs from router with `enableTracing: true` but cant figure this one out

Comment: When I need to redirect within a guard I usually inject the router and do `this.router.navigate([ routeA ])` then you can force to always run guards and resolvers on your route (if nessecary) with [runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'](https://angular.io/api/router/RunGuardsAndResolvers)

Answer (score 0):

After searching for couple of days for a solution, I decided to just force the calls of logic from canActivate in outside functions. It seems that there i no reliable way of doing this, maybe by hijacking the router path with `this.router.navigate` but it seems to be a hit or miss for me :(